# Why return type from PowerShell function is always an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to write a PowerShell function to execute JavaScript/jQuery on a web page and return the results back to PowerShell with this trick that we store the JavaScript return value in the DOM using `setAttribute` and then retrieving it in PowerShell using `getAttribute`. However, the following problem is bugging me for few days now. Please see below for comments:

```
Function ExecJavaScript($ie, $jsCommand, [switch]$global)
{
    if (!$global) {
        $jsCommand = "document.body.setAttribute('PSResult', (function(){$jsCommand})());"
    }
    $document = $ie.document
    $window = $document.parentWindow
    $window.execScript($jsCommand, 'javascript')
    if (!$global) {
        $psresult = $document.body.getAttribute('PSResult')

        # Why no matter what I do, this always returns an array instead of a String?
        return $psresult.ToString()
        #return @($psresult)
        #return @($psresult).ToString()
        #return ($psresult | select -First 1)
        #return ($psresult -join '')
    }
}

$ie = New-Object -COM InternetExplorer.Application -Property @{
    Navigate = "https://www.google.com/"
    Visible = $true
}
do { Start-Sleep -m 100 } while ( $ie.busy )

$result = ExecJavaScript $ie @'
    return "JavaScript code ran successfully!";
'@

# Why $result.length is always 2 ?!!
$result.length
$result
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance this command: $window.execScript($jsCommand, 'javascript') is outputting a return that polluting the pipeline?  If it is, you redirect that to $null: $window.execScript($jsCommand, 'javascript') > $null

Comment: Documentation of [execScript method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536420(v=vs.85).aspx) says it always returns null. Nonetheless, I piped it to `Out-Null` and that fixed the problem! :)... though, I still don't understand it.

Comment: I will accept it as answer if you explain it a little in an answer post. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really have an explanation.  I just recognized those symptoms, and that command was the only candidate I saw for being a possible source of extraneous output.

Comment: Thanks anyways. My problem is solved with your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, returning null  is different from returning to null. The execScript method returns null, which is in fact an object out to the pipeline. I hope the snippet below explains the behavior you are experiencing.

```
Function ReturnNull () {

    0..1 | % { $null }
}

Function ReturnToNull() {

    0..1 | % { $null | Out-Null }
}

# This will return 2.
(ReturnNull).length

# This will return 0 as it has been spit out to Null.
(ReturnToNull).length
```

Your function was basically `ReturnNull` and changed to `ReturnToNull` when you added the `Out-Null` cmdlet.